# Problemas para listar BD MYSQL no eclipse

Tags: mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou tendo um problema em meu código Java na hora de listar o BD do MySQL no Eclipse.

Acontece que quando coloco para listar os dados, ele está listando as informações 3 vezes mas quando faço o `SELECT * FROM` no MySQL os dados estão sendo listados corretamente. Alguém pode me ajudar? Abaixo está o método para listar os dados.

```
public void listarClientes() {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM locadora.cliente, locadora.endereco";

    try {

        PreparedStatement ps = jdbc.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


        while (rs.next()) {

            System.out.println("Nome: " + rs.getString("nome") + " - Código: " + rs.getString("codigo") + " - Bom pagador: " + rs.getBoolean("seBomPagador")
            + " - Telefone: " + rs.getString("telefone"));

            System.out.println("Tipo de endereço: " + rs.getString("tipo_endereco") + " - Logradouro: " + rs.getString("logradouro") + " - Bairro: "
                    + rs.getString("bairro") + " - Cidade: " + rs.getString("cidade") + " - UF: " + rs.getString("uf") + " - Cep: " + rs.getString("cep"));

            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

        System.out.println("Erro na listagem dos clientes!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Sem saber os dados das tabelas, a saída do programa e o que deveria de fato retornar, fica difícil dar uma resposta precisa (se quiser - e eu sugiro que o faça - você pode **[edit]** a pergunta, de modo que ela seja um [mcve]). Somente com as informações que estão na pergunta até o momento, eu chutaria que ao invés de `FROM locadora.cliente, locadora.endereco`, você deveria fazer um JOIN com as tabelas cliente e endereco. Mas é só um chute...

Comment: O problema no teu caso não é a listagem, e sim a query, que não está tendo um relacionamento entre as tabelas.

Comment: Como resolvo isso?